# Why are Oracle functions faster to return cached values than Views when queried from Tableau?

Tags: plsql, tableau-api

I have an Oracle View that has it's main SQL decorated with a **/*+ RESULT CACHE */** and when I query it, I can see that the cached values are returning fast in SQLDbx, which is good.

But, when the same select * is done from Tableau, it never seems to use the cached query! It always takes the full time.

However when I wrap this View with a function, making the function return this View's data as a table, then Tableau gets the data faster!

Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm not convinced this description proves that Oracle functions are faster to return cached values than views. Perhaps Tableau interferes with caching somehow.

Comment: As far as I know, Tableau creates its own queries, given the data sources and it might just consider the View's components as separate and ignore the hint. What you can do to prove that is change the View definition, so that it uses an inefficient join and let Tableau alter that if it really works like that. Ther than that, I see no reason why Tableau would alter the view and ignore the hint, but what I do know is that till some version hints are not supported (might as well be the last one). One more thing - are you sure you ran the query as least one time before running it with Tableau ?

Comment: g00dy, the hint is used within the View's definition, so Tableau really doesn't have to use the hint in it's query. And yes, ran several times - to see same behavior.